# Converting SQL Server text column to image datatype

Tags: sql-server, image, t-sql, text, types

I have an issue where I am updating a note column in SQL Server 2008 R2 which is an `Image` datatype with the value of a column in another table which is a `text` column.

I can convert from `image` to `text` easy enough but not the other way around. My data wont go above 4000 characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Hi @marc_s, Thank you for the info. I will change to `varchar(max)` in my source table. However, my image table talks to a CRM so I will have to wait for the developer to use `varbinary(max)` in his next update. For the time being, is there a way (or know of any StackOverFlow links) to help convert `varchar(max)` to `image`?

Comment: @BMJ Can you please share how you're converting image to text?